# PHP include method is not working on hosting for back directories but working on localhost

Tags: php

I want to include a file that in 1 directory back folder, it is working on localhost but is not working on hosting. Hosting is Godaddy.
Here is the code:

```
<?php include('/../loc/pos/summary.php'); ?>
```

Comment: `/../` amounts to `/` the root directory.

Comment: I think /../ is already in the code, can you explain how exactly should  I add?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
<?php include( __DIR__.'/../loc/pos/summary.php'); ?>
```

Comment: Awesome! It's working. Thanks, Mahmood Morid.